# Assigning variables inside if brackets and using them outside

Tags: java

I declared the variable outside the if and depending on various things assigned it within the if. The thing is, checking in debug mode showed that after it left the if block, the variable returned to being uninitialized for some reason.

The code looks something like this:

```
function() {
    double x;
    if (something happens) {
        x = some_func();
    }
}
```

some_func() works, and when I put a breakpoint within the if brackets, the x is shown with the correct value, yet once outside, it goes back to being uninitialized (as mentioned before). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to print x after the if statement. Perhaps the debugger is not showing the correct value.

Comment: Post your proper code. This *pseudo-code* will work fine and give you the desired behaviour.

Comment: Since you are asking about `javascript` I am re-tagging your question.

Comment: Actually, it IS java, so re-tagged.

nevermind, the problem was with me not understanding boolean variables apparently. (further down the line).

Answer (score 0):

As per The pseudo-code posted by you all you need to do is that initialize the `variable x` at the declaration time or before printing as you are initializing the variable in a conditional statement and as we know that *all the local variables need to be initialized before use in Java* you get the variable uninitialized error.

For example we have :-

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static int check()
    {
        int c=10;
        return c;
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        int a=1,x=5;
        if (a==1) {
        x = check();
        }
        System.out.println("hello World"+x);
     }
}
```

in this example if you remove the initialization section of variable x from the above example you get the variable uninitialized error else it will work fine.

So simple solution to your problem keeping your pseudo code in mind is that you can initialize the `variable x` at the time of declaration.